# How do you find the locationURI of menu contributions?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've managed to add an item to the popup menu when the user right-clicks on a file in the Project Explorer by adding something like this:

```
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="commands.mycmd"
               label="do foo"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Now, the only reason I knew to use `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer` is because that is what everyone else seems to be doing (there is no record of this in Eclipse PDE documentation). The problem is that I want the same functionality in the Navigator and the Package Explorer views as well (right-click on a file and you can do "do foo" as in the Project Explorer. **How do I find the locationURI of these other two views (Package Explorer and Navigator)?**

I've tried the  `alt+shift+F2` tip to find such information but Eclipse does not allow you to get the information of the tab itself when you activate this mode.

Comment: If you use `ALT+SHIFT+F1` on the view, it will list the IDs of registered context menus.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick :). It is somewhat documented here: http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/

Comment: @PaulWebster Thanks! You need to post this as the answer.

Answer (score -4):

Use

```
locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.any?after=additions">
```

It will do the trick.

Comment: It solves the problem, but does't answer the question: how to find out the valid URIs.