# How do you find the locationURI of menu contributions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am very sorry that I asked an exactly same question to [How do you find the locationURI of menu contributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222484/how-do-you-find-the-locationuri-of-menu-contributions)
http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/ disappears without leaving any tip what the substitute is 
I search books and get some common location like:

menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions

toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions

popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.any?after=additions

alt+thift+f2 worked for some menu. but not all.

It is hurt when you don't know how to do something. but it is more hurt you know how to do but you lack of a thing that you know it exists and you can't get it.

Comment: Read about Eclipse [menu spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#menu-spy)

Comment: Thank you for your sharing。by using menu spy, I can get the information of menu, but I don't know how to get the groupId,